# Downloading JavaScript-loaded audio using Selenium and Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to write a script to automate the downloading of the text and audio files from a website, using Python and Selenium.

The website: https://learn.dict.naver.com/conversation#/korean-en/20190713 (yyyymmdd)

```
import requests
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

url = 'https://learn.dict.naver.com/conversation#/korean-en/20190713'

options = Options()
options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path = 'geckodriver')
driver.get(url)
sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn_listen').click() #for the first one
```

The audio plays/loads on click, but I don't know how to "capture" the file as it loads and download it.

For example, the first play button loads this URL:
https://dict-dn.pstatic.net/v?_lsu_sa_=3348a15dcd343766a69b01513e9444f36d1462055f0edfbd60a21c73bbe96741685d375f6b45b579a9df6f95d82950485fa22dddfc987cc04ba7a344d3daaff10b8f5ed218b169623e2b926412981ebffcd2ee2a025bbfea806ec1ee58c519fab30368be2e72c258347eb029646cd69ca0c931d102f1fcdef76df1a85dc49c52df2a6431603057d8f62c0c613ec86b1c

Copying that into the browser, an audio file loads that can be downloaded manually. I want to download it automatically (bonus points for being able to rename it dynamically).

I've already tried a few options.set_preference()s, but they seem to primarily relate to a file which is meant to download (i.e. a "Click here to download" button), not simply play.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [requests](/questions/tagged/requests) to download mp3 files and get other useful information about sentences in text format on the page.
Below code is example for the https://learn.dict.naver.com/conversation#/korean-en/20190713. Use json in `data` variable to see information you can use.

```
import requests
import json

callback = 'angular.callbacks._0'

headers = {
    'Referer': 'https://learn.dict.naver.com/conversation',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36',
    'DNT': '1',
}
params = (
    ('callback', callback),
)

with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.get('https://gateway.dict.naver.com/krdict/kr/koen/today/20190713/conversation.dict',
                           headers=headers, params=params)

    data = json.loads(response.text.lstrip(f"{callback}(").rstrip(")"))["data"]
    sentences = data["sentences"]

    for sentence in sentences:
        audio_id = sentence["id"]
        sentence_pron_file = sentence["sentence_pron_file"]

        response = requests.post(f'https://learn.dict.naver.com/dictPronunciation.dict?filePaths={sentence_pron_file}')
        audio_url = response.json()["url"][0]
        audio_file = session.get(audio_url)

        with open(f'./{audio_id}.mp3', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(audio_file.content)
```

Comment: That is... Perfect. Thank you so much. Now I have to try and understand it all haha!

How did you even know about the conversation.dict? That makes everything so much easier!